# Javascript Local Storage seems to be loading nonexistent items

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I have a simple to-do list app and I want to save/load the added items. I'm using the following code to add an item to localStorage each time an item is added:

`localStorage.setItem("LIST_ITEM_" + makeid(24), uinput); //makeid() generates random strings`

I'm setting the key to LIST_ITEM_ and a random 24-character string

I am using the following code to load items from localStorage:

```
for (i in localStorage) { // Iterate through the cookies
    for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(localStorage)) { // Create key-value pairs for each
        if (key.includes("LIST_ITEM")) { // Check if the key is a LIST_ITEM
            // Create elements to display the item
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes in on the page where it seems to load each item 8 times instead of just once as it should.

I ran this code to see what was inside localStorage:
`for (i in localStorage) {console.log(localStorage[i])}`

And got this:

```
ww
VM1809:1 w
VM1809:1 2
VM1809:1 ƒ clear() { [native code] }
VM1809:1 ƒ getItem() { [native code] }
VM1809:1 ƒ key() { [native code] }
VM1809:1 ƒ removeItem() { [native code] }
VM1809:1 ƒ setItem() { [native code] }
```

The keys that have actually been input are "w," and "ww".

The page displays:

```
w
ww
```

8 times.

Not sure what I've done wrong but that is definitely not supposed to happen.

Comment: You meant to use `console.log(i)` (or maybe `console.log(i, localStorage[i])`), not `console.log(localStorage[i])`. That's logging the value you had stored, not the keys.

Comment: @Bergi But he never stored `clear() { [native code] }`

Comment: Btw, instead of `key.includes("LIST_ITEM")` use `key.startsWith("LIST_ITEM_")`. Or ideally just store them in a single array, not as multiple items with distinct keys.

Comment: Also, doing both `for (i in localStorage)` and `for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(localStorage))` is redundant. You want only one of those loops, not nest both of them.

Comment: @Barmar Well that's just what you get when you use `for (i in localStorage)`, `LocalStorage` methods are enumerable. I don't think this a problem here

Comment: @Bergi That's the whole problem -- it's why they're getting output other than the items they stored.

Comment: @Barmar No. `i.includes("LIST_ITEM")` would take care of that and filter out the unwanted methods. The actual problem - why they are getting their 2 items printed 8 times instead of once - is the nested loops.

Comment: They're not getting 2 items printed 8 times. They got the two expected items `ww` and `w`. Then they got `localStorage.length`, `localStorage.clear`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over an object, it also gets enumerable properties inherited from the prototype. In the case of `localStorage`, that includes all the methods. Use `hasOwnProperty()` to filter out the inherited properties.

```
for (i in localStorage) {
  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i, localStorage[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get to 746K and not see this as an obvious dupe?